# How do I change the content of table cells using jQuery and then dynamically add more when I run out?

Tags: jquery, html-table, css-selectors

I have a table with three columns. I create a string in PHP that separates "id" and corresponding data by commas. those pairs are separated by exclamation points so that I can use them in this way. I want to fill each table cell with data and assign it an id so that I can use the ID later for a mysql query if that object is clicked. when I have filled the row and need more columns I want to add another row. when the array containing the id-data pairs is empty I want to break the loop. I have no idea what I'm doing so please be detailed. After days of research this is what I could gather and it is not even close to producing results.

```
$("#class").keyup(function () 
    {
        $.post("classSearch.php",
    {
            class:$(this).serialize(),
        },
        function(data)
        {   
            if (data == "notFound") 
            {
                $("#searchResults td").siblings(":first").text("No Results");
            }
            else
            {
                var counter = 0;
                var resultsTemp= data.split("!");
                var iterations = resultsTemp.size();
                $("#searchResults td:first").each(function() 
                {       
                    if (counter == iterations) 
                    {return false;}
                    if((counter % 3) == 0)
                    {$("#searchResults td").siblings(":last").append("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");}
                    var results = resultsTemp.split(",");
                    $(this).text(results[(1)]);
                    $(this).attr("id",results[0]);
                    counter ++; 
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

HTML

```
<table  id="searchResults">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So you want to group the data downloaded into sets of three, add them to a row, and move on to the next row for the next set of three, right?

Comment: Not exactly. I want to one by one change the id of the "td" and add text to it. once I'm on the last cell of the row I just want to add another row and repeat until I'm out of data. The data coming from the php file contains **all** of the pairs not just three.

Comment: check the data type of resultTemp...im afraid it's already array thus cannot be splitted

Comment: Good point. I can split the string in results[counter] though. I'll change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty out the table and leave it just as `<table id="searchResults"></table>`

Now, if the data returns no results, you can simply do this:

```
$("#searchResults").append("<tr><td>Nothing returned</td></tr>");
```

Inside the `else` (i.e., when you have data), do the following:

```
var resultsTemp = data.split('!');
var addToTable = '';
var totalElements = resultsTemp.length;
for (var i=0; i<totalElements/3; i++) {
    if (i%3 == 0)
        // Beginning a new row
        addToTable += '<tr>';

    // Parse and get the id and value from each element
    var elemId = resultsTemp[i].split(',')[0];
    var elemValue = resultsTemp[i].split(',')[1];
    addToTable += '<td id="'+elemId+'">'+elemValue+'</td>';

    if (i%3 == 2)
        // End of row
        addToTable += '</tr>\n';
}

// If the total set was not an exact multiple of 3
// you will need to close the row
if (totalElements %3 !=0)
    addToTable += '</tr>\n';

$("#searchResults").append(addToTable);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is much more simple.

Comment: I didn't have enough points to vote yesterday. Some magically appeared so there you have it. :)